# Returning data from js function not arriving in calling function

Tags: javascript, electron

I am following the Electron filesystem tutorial here:

[How to choose , read, save, delete or create a file with Electron Framework](http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/106/how-to-choose-read-save-delete-or-create-a-file-with-electron-framework)

Which includes the following code to pull up a load file dialog:

```
        document.getElementById('select-file').addEventListener('click',function(){
            dialog.showOpenDialog(function (fileNames) {
                if(fileNames === undefined){
                    console.log("No file selected");
                }else{
                    document.getElementById("actual-file").value = fileNames[0];
                    readFile(fileNames[0]);
                    // myData = readFile(fileNames[0]);  <--- 
                }
            }); 
        },false);
```

And the following code to actually read the file:

```
        function readFile(filepath) {
            fs.readFile(filepath, 'utf-8', function (err, data) {
                if(err){
                    alert("An error ocurred reading the file :" + err.message);
                    return;
                }

                document.getElementById("content-editor").value = data;
            });
        }
```

As you can see, the last line updates the DOM with the imported data.  However, I want to return the data to my calling function because it isn't HTML.  Note the commented line towards the end of the first snipped.  That's the kind of thing I want to do.

It's actually XML that has to be processed rather than dumped into the DOM.  But all my attempts to return data (notably, 'return data;' either where the last line is or before the final curly brace) have failed.  Neither results in the calling function getting the data.

Is it possible that the calling function needs to wait for this one to complete?  Or, more likely, I'm just not returning the data correctly from this type of function.  Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your `readFile(filepath)` is performing the async file read operation you cannot use the simple return here. However you can pass a callback to your `readFile` function and call it later whenever your read operation is completed with the data. Like this.

Create a callback

```
function fileReadComplete(data) {
    myData = data;
    // Do whatever you want
}
```

and And call it as .

```
readFile(fileNames[0], fileReadComplete);
```

Change your readfile function:

```
function readFile(filepath, callback) {
        fs.readFile(filepath, 'utf-8', function (err, data) {
            if(err){
                alert("An error ocurred reading the file :" + err.message);
                return;
            }
            callback(data);
            document.getElementById("content-editor").value = data;
        });
    }
```

Comment: This worked well.  This way I can also call it from ctrl-L as well as the File menu and right-clicking on the background.  This should let me do all of that.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understood, this should do what you want.

// Update; changed from "return" to callback function.

```
    document.getElementById('select-file').addEventListener('click',function(){
        dialog.showOpenDialog(function (fileNames) {
            if(fileNames === undefined){
                console.log("No file selected");
            }else{
                document.getElementById("actual-file").value = fileNames[0];


                readFile(fileNames[0], function(myData){
                 console.log(myData);
                });

            }
        }); 
    },false);

    function readFile(filepath, callBack) {
        fs.readFile(filepath, 'utf-8', function (err, data) {
            if(err){
                alert("An error ocurred reading the file :" + err.message);
                return;
            }
            callBack(data);
            //document.getElementById("content-editor").value = data;
        });
    }
```

Comment: This won't work, `fs.readFile` is async function and readFile function will immediately return with no value.